# Making a rounded bar for "contact button" in a navbar

Tags: html, css

I have to make something like a contact button; I don't know exactly what to call this. I have this image:

[image: "menu"]

And I made:

[image: menu2]

Someone could please help? I tried to put the images in a div and change its background and do something with its radius, but it didn't work :(

HTML:

```html
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf230; | </i>
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf232; | </i>
```

CSS:

```css
#menu1 i { 
  width: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code for what you currently have.

Comment: Is the CSS in the same file as the HTML? Where is your CSS for the background color?

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried to change the background, but it doens't work. I mean, the background around the icons gets green like I want, but it gets really wierd with some spaces between the icons. I was thinking if there's something like the first image on the internet, something already made...But I couldn't find anything :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/ryuchix/w9tohLs2/1/

```
<div id="menu1">
 <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>|<span class="fa fa-phone"></span>|
 <p>Fone: 11 3854-0200</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu1 {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
#menu1 span {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#menu1 p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `<i></i>` in a `<div id="menu1"></div>` then just call the #menu1 in your css

When you define '#menu1 i' in your css you are formating both of your 'i' separately. Then what you want to do is include them inside the same box. You are applying the formats to that.

```css
#menu1 {
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu1">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook">|</i><i class="fa fa-phone">|</i>
</div>
```